# optimizing the jquery in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have done the following code which actually dynamically generate the values in the third list box using ajax and jquery concepts. Thoug it works, i need to optimize it. Below is the code i am working on now.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comparison based on ID Number</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>     
</head>
<body>   
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/idnumber/" method="post" align= "center">{% csrf_token %}        
         <p>Select different id numbers and the name of the <b> Measurement Group </b>to start the comparison</p>         
         <table align = "center">
         <tr>
            <th><label for="id_criteria_1">Id Number 1:</label></th>
            <th>        {{ form.idnumber_1 }}           </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="id_criteria_2">Id Number 2:</label></th>
            <th>        {{ form.idnumber_2 }}               </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="group_name_list">Group Name:</label></th>
            <th><select name="group_name_list" id="id_group_name_list">
            <option>Select</option>         
            </select>
            </th>
         </tr>   
         <script>
         $('#id_idnumber_2').change(
        function get_group_names()
        {
            var value1 = $('#id_idnumber_1').attr('value');
            var value2 = $(this).attr('value');         
            alert(value1);
            alert(value2);
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "/getGroupnamesforIDnumber/",
                type: "GET",
                data: {idnumber_1 : value1,idnumber_2 : value2},            
                dataType: "json",               
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    var myselect = document.getElementById("group_name_list");  
                    document.getElementById("group_name_list").options.length = 1;
                    var length_of_data = data.length;
                    alert(length_of_data);
                    try{        
                        for(var i = 0;i < length_of_data; i++)                  
                        {
                            myselect.add(new Option(data[i].group_name, "i"), myselect.options[i]) //add new option to beginning of "sample"
                        }
                        }
                        catch(e){ //in IE, try the below version instead of add()
                            for(var i = 0;i < length_of_data; i++)
                            {
                                myselect.add(new Option(data[i].group_name, data[i].group_name)) //add new option to end of "sample"                        
                            }                   
                        }               
        }
        });
        });
         </script>

        <tr align = "center"><th><input type="submit" value="Submit"></th></tr> 
         </table>         
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

everything works fine but there is a little problem in my code. (ie) my ajax function calls only when there is a change in the select list 2 (ie) 'id_number_2'. I want to  make it call in such a way that which ever select box, the third list box should be updated automatically.

Can anyone please help me on this with a possible logical solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger ajax change function if any of the two list box changes.

change:

```
$('#id_idnumber_2').change(
```

to

```
$('select[id^="id_idnumber"]').change(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#id_idnumber_2, #id_idnumber_1').live('change', function(){
 function get_group_names()
    {
     // Your code here
    }
 });
```